# Focal - Exclude disk from update-grub

Tags: boot, grub2, laptop, sd-card, 20.04

My new laptop has a built-in card reader. Unlike previous laptops, the card reader shows as a standard USB disk (/dev/sdb) rather than a dedicated PCIe device (/dev/mmcblk). As such, GRUB seems to scan it when running `update-grub`, which produces an error since there's no card in the reader:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
...
```

It's not problematic, but it's annoying to see this unnecessary spam. I've tried adding `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` to `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`, and `chmod -x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`, but each time it still checks `/dev/sdb`, so I'm not sure where the call is.

I only have Ubuntu on this laptop and only on a single SSD, so scanning any other disk is not necessary. I installed it with 19.10 and upgraded to 20.04 this month. Can I disable the scan?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1834250

Answer (score 0):

I would like to summarize the [bug1834259](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1834250) mentioned from mook765.

What worked for me:

I use lvm2 on the root disk (I am not sure, if this works without using lvm).

As mentioned in the [bug1834259](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1834250) I added a global filter to the deivces section in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`.

First lookup in `/dev/disk/by-id` which filter to add.

```
# ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
total 0
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  8 17:23 usb-Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE_00001-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  8 17:23 usb-Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE_00001-0:1 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  8 17:23 usb-Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE_00001-0:2 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  8 17:23 usb-Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE_00001-0:3 -> ../../sde
```

In my case the usb-Generic pointed to the cardreader devices.

To filter these devices out, my global filter looks like this:

```
global_filter = [ "r|/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic.*|" ]
```

Be aware that this is a regular expression between the `|`.
The `r` at the beginning means "remove".

It might be there is a more clever solution, but this worked for me.